# ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available - Only with many requests

Tags: spring-integration

I am running the client portion of the Spring Integration TCP Multiplex example. I was trying to see how many requests it could handle at once and around 1000, I started to get this error: ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Everything is fine below about 1000 calls.

```
<beans:description>
        Uses conversion service and collaborating channel adapters.
    </beans:description>

    <context:property-placeholder />

    <converter>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.ByteArrayToStringConverter" />
    </converter>

    <!-- Fastest Wire Protocol - takes a byte array with its length definied in the first x bytes-->
    <beans:bean id="fastestWireFormatSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Client side -->

    <gateway id="gw"
        service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.SimpleGateway"
        default-request-channel="input" />

    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
        type="client"
        host="localhost"
        port="${availableServerSocket}"
        single-use="false"
        serializer="fastestWireFormatSerializer"
        deserializer="fastestWireFormatSerializer"
        so-timeout="10000" />

    <publish-subscribe-channel id="input" />

    <!-- scheduler - Thread used to restablish connection so the other threads aren't starved while waiting to re-establish connection -->
    <!-- client-mode - Automatically re-establishes the connection if lost -->
    <ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.client"
        order="2"
        channel="input"
        client-mode="true"              
        connection-factory="client" />  <!-- Collaborator -->



    <!-- Also send a copy to the custom aggregator for correlation and
         so this message's replyChannel will be transferred to the
         aggregated message.
         The order ensures this gets to the aggregator first -->
    <bridge input-channel="input" output-channel="toAggregator.client"
            order="1"/>

    <!-- Asynch receive reply -->
    <ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.client"
        channel="toAggregator.client"
        connection-factory="client" /> <!-- Collaborator -->

    <!-- dataType attribute invokes the conversion service, if necessary -->
    <channel id="toAggregator.client" datatype="java.lang.String" />

    <aggregator input-channel="toAggregator.client"
        output-channel="toTransformer.client"
        correlation-strategy-expression="payload.substring(0,3)"
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true" />

    <transformer input-channel="toTransformer.client"
        expression="payload.get(1)"/> <!-- The response is always second -->

    <task:scheduler id="reconnectScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

And the code used to test:

```
        TaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(100);
        final Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 100; i < 1050; i++) {
            results.add(i);
            final int j = i;
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String result = gateway.send(j + "Hello world!"); // first 3 bytes is correlationid
                    System.out.println("Test Result: " + result);
                    results.remove(j);
                    latch.countDown();
                }});
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out entirely why you are getting that exception, but there are several problems with your test.

1. The countdown latch needs to be initialized at 950
2. Since you are exceeding 999, we need to change the correlation:

   `payload.substring(0,4)`

With those changes, it works for me.

<s>I'll try to figure out why we're getting that exception when I get a bit more time.</s>

**EDIT**

The issue is indeed caused by the conflicting correlation ids.

The last 50 messages all have correlation id `100` which means messages are released in an indeterminate fashion (given the release is based on size). In some cases two input messages are released (causing the wrong reply to the test case). When 2 replies are released; there is no output channel.